# Member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name

Tags: c#

Today I was working on c sharp and I'm trying out static classes, but it doesn't seem to work for me and I would love to know the solution.
I have been browsing around the web for a while now but I can't seem to find the answer.

Here is my code:

```
class Count
{
    public static int sum(int add1, int add2)
    {
        int result = add1 + add2;
        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
   static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding: \nPlease enter the first number");
        int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number");
        int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Count add = new Count();
        int total = add.sum(num1, num2);
        Console.WriteLine("The sum is {0}.", total);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Count.sum` instead of an instance.

Comment: You see this error because `sum` is `static`. Follow the Search Results
recommendation of dcg.

Answer (score 10):

`sum` is not an instance method, it must be accessed via its type.  Replace this:

```
Count add = new Count();
int total = add.sum(num1, num2);
```

With this:

```
int total = Count.sum(num1, num2);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to use static classes - mark the Count class as static - like so:

```
public static class Count
```

and then use the following in your code:

```
int total = Count.sum(num1, num2);
```

And it should work as expected.

Comment: he does say `static classes`, so he does probably want that.  But whether or not `Count` is static doesn't affect how he should call `sum`

Comment: @Jonesopolis Correct, it just saves him marking every method as static if he described what he was trying to achieve correctly - Worth noting however.